# How do I set a Word add-in to open automatically?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

When you install an Word add-in an icon appears in the ribbon, and the user has to click on the icon in order to open the add-in

Is there a way to make an Word add-in open automatically every time Word starts up, without the need to click the button?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure that in the add-in manifest with the `AutoShowTaskpaneInDocument` setting. There are details in the docs here: [Automatically Open a Task Pane with a Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document).

Comment: If I understand correctly `AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument` seems to allow Word to "remember" if an add in has been opened (which is good!). Is there a way to give the user the option of always having the add-in open automatically even on new documents?

Comment: @Fergie I'm afraid not.